# Access to WMS from ArcMap with extra parameters

Tags: arcmap, wms

I'm trying to access [AIRS WMS](http://disc1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/daac-bin/wms_airs?) from ArcMap with additional time parameter (&TIME=2012-07-01) to see this summer's CO concentration. But the server returns a response with standard parameters (last month).

How to pass this parameters in the ArcMap WMS-connection correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure if ArcMap could support time enabled WMS but it looks like it [**should be able to**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sp0000001n000000.htm) - at least from 10.0 onwards.

From the link above I found this text:

"If the service supports time, you will see the Time tab of the Layer Properties dialog box."

I have not found anything to say that ArcMap can display a time enabled WMS using a single particular time but you would think that should be easier for Esri to implement than linking it to a time slider.  There is an ArcGIS Idea for [**WMS temporal support**](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008FpPAAU) that mentions your exact requirement (and the time slider one) but it looks like it has not yet reached "Under Consideration" status.  I recommend you vote for it and make a comment to ensure they know the part you are after is the "support for WMS at single point in time" part.